# Conditional types with mypy

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, strong-typing

I have the following code snippet:

```py
from typing import TypedDict

class Super(TypedDict):
    foo: int

class SubA(Super):
    bar: int

class SubB(Super):
    zap: int

def print_props(inp: Super, key: str):
    print(inp[key])
```

When I call the method `print_props` with either an instance of `SubA` or `SubB` it would be valid as they are sub types of `Super`.

But `mypy` will complain about `inp[key]` as the `key` must be literal `"foo"`.
Is it possible to give `mypy` hints so that it is capable of deciding which keys are valid?
For example: "When `print_props` is called with an instance of `SubB` only `"foo"` and `"zap"` are valid."

I took a look at [generics](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html); I think it is possible to declare a type variable that is restricted to sub types of `Super`, but is it possible to express the dependency between the concrete type of the type variable (`SubA` or `SubB`) and the literal values key should then be restricted to?

Comment: `SubA` and `SubB` aren't subtypes of `Super`, though. They subclass from `TypedDict`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overloads with `Literal` could well do it, though I do wonder if a different design would be better. I'm a bit concerned about the increasingly frequent usage of `overload` and `Literal` in SO answers. They both suggest a design smell to me

```
@overload
def printMyProps(input: SubA, key: Literal["foo", "bar"]) -> None: ...

@overload
def printMyProps(input: SubB, key: Literal["foo", "zap"]) -> None: ...

def printMyProps(input: SubA | SubB, key: Literal["foo", "bar", "zap"]) -> None:
  print(input[key])  # type: ignore
```

I've used `type: ignore` because it's a short function and I can't use `isinstance` on `TypedDict`. TBH `overload` implementations often require type hacks. The API works as intended though

Comment: This is the right way to do it. Personally, I think `overload` is perfectly fine. I think introducing `TypedDict` was the mistake. It basically nudges people towards misusing dictionaries instead of using objects. It encourages artificially restricting a perfectly nice generic mapping type (`dict`) in situations where you should just create your own class with the attributes you need. Not a fan.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg For me `TypedDict` is a good 'utility' type to make legacy code that deals a lot with dictionaries typesafe. I think the solution provided by @joel is the right one for me. Anyway I miss an operator like [keyof](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator) as TypeScript provides it . A `keyof` like operator would make it possible to define the valid keys dependent from the type of `input`.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg `TypedDict` is needed to describe things like JSON-based interfaces that are defined to return dicts with a specific structure.

Otherwise, ... `@dataclass` is your friend!

Except ... I came here looking for `keyof`, because I want a type based on another `@dataclass`-based class, except typed with values all `bool`.